# Using d3.js to create an SVG at several divs

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

Suppose I have some HTML which looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class = "a"></div>
...
<div class = "a"></div>
...
<div class = "a"></div>
...
</body>
<html>
```

where the ...'s are just paragraphs or other code.

**Problem:**  I'd like to be able to use d3.js to append an SVG at each of these div's.

For example, let's say I want to make a rectangle like:

```
var svg = ((SOMETHING GOES HERE!))
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", h);

var sep = svg.selectAll("rect")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 10)
```

How can I use the selectors on the first line to do this?  I've tried `selectall()` and `select()` with various "div.a", ".", etc., things, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just append the SVG to your div with:

```
d3.selectAll("div.a").append("svg")
```

And if you want to select and act upon those SVGs after you made them just add a sub-select:

```
d3.selectAll("div.a").select("svg").append("rect").attr("height", 50).attr("width", 50)
```

Or you could class your SVGs and select them after you made them:

```
d3.selectAll("div.a").append("svg").attr("class", "divSVG")
d3.selectAll("svg.divSVG).append("rect").attr("height", 50).attr("width", 50)
```

Also, if you want them to appear before your

elements, use insert instead of append:

```
d3.selectAll("div.a").insert("svg", "p")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  I even had an "ah-ha" moment with selectors because of this --- fantastic!

Comment: @elijah this is great. thank you so much for taking the time to answer this question. it helped me as well!